# Hide errors in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm asking for help in vscode, do you know how to hide errors in the code ? I mean when it's underlining in red the code. There's an error printed but this isn't a real error so...
[underlining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bez1f.png). It's not a code error, I'm not asking for help on my program but on my editor. Thanks.

I tried to look into the settings but I didn't not found anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

file -> preferences -> settings.

then click this icon"
[image]

then add (for the yellow lines):

```
"css.lint.emptyRules": "ignore",
```

and (for the red lines)

```
first off check for "workbench.colorCustimazations"

this is an array of settings, if it does not exist. make it.

if it exists, add this:

"editorError.foreground": #00000000,
"editorWarning.foreground": #00000000,
"editorInfo.foreground": #00000000
```

the 2 extra zero's on the end make them transparent.
reference vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vR2y4VoCZg4

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is for hiding all the errors, how can I hide especially one error ? do you know ?

Comment: not possible, i know you can 'ignore all' in word but ive never seen it here